# Multiple access to the same HTML file on a standard file server over a LAN

Tags: html, lan

I have a requirement to create an HTML file that will contain a `.swf` (flash) object that will reside on a server on a LAN. Multiple users, on the LAN, will access the file from each of their terminals at the same time.

Will there be an issue if many users are trying to access the file at the same time? I understand the network isnt the best and the server is just a regular file server.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the computer and the network traffic. File servers are able to handle multiple requests but if an incredibly high number of requests come in the computational power on the server might not be able to handle it. However, let it roll and if there are issues, consider upgrading the specs on the server computer.